# reference system variable in exec sql tasks in different containers in ssis package

Tags: ssis, teradata, bids, sql-server-data-tools

I need to load about 40 flat files into 40 different tables and log each one into a stats table after it's loaded.  I've named my tasks to match the table names and created onPostExecute events with an execSQL task in each of them (they're all copies of the task I made first.)

I have a variable at the package scope containing the SQL I'd like to execute including a reference to the system variable @[System::SourceName]:

```
"INSERT INTO db.TableStatsHistory SELECT * FROM db.TableStats WHERE TABLENAME = '" + @[System::SourceName] + "'; " + 
"DELETE FROM db.TableStats WHERE TABLENAME = '" + @[System::SourceName] + "'; " +
"INSERT INTO db.TableStats 
 SELECT t.tname ,CURRENT_DATE ,rcnt ,sum_currentPerm  FROM
 (SELECT databasename, TABLENAME AS tname FROM dbc.TablesV) t INNER JOIN
 (SELECT databasename, TABLENAME AS tname, SUM(currentPerm) AS sum_currentPerm FROM dbc.TableSize GROUP BY 1,2 ) ts ON
 t.databasename = ts.databasename AND t.tname = ts.tname INNER JOIN
 (SELECT '" + @[System::SourceName] + "' AS tname, COUNT(*) AS rcnt FROM db." + @[System::SourceName] + ") u ON
 t.tname = u.tname WHERE  t.databasename = 'db' AND t.tname = '" + @[System::SourceName] + "'"
```

When I only had one task enabled for development, it ran fine, but now that I've pasted that task into 39 other onPostExecute events, it says:

```
    Error: The variable "System::SourceName" was not found in the Variables collection. 
The variable might not exist in the correct scope.
```

I'm not real clear on the concept of 'scope' for SSIS variables, but the examples I've seen say to create your user variable at the package level.  If I first click on a task in an event and then open the variable's Expression window, it evaluates just fine.

I'm hoping I don't have to create multiple variables and/or tasks at each scope to get this to work, I only want the SQL statement in one place referenced by each data flow task's onPostExecute event, but I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141085.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Scope

You can change this property setting only by clicking Move Variable in the Variables window.
A variable is created within the scope of a package or within the scope of a container, task, 
or event handler in the package. Because the package container is at the top of the container 
hierarchy, variables with package scope function like global variables and can be used by all 
containers in the package.
```

so why can't the package find the system variable?

Thanks for any help,

-Beth

I can get it to work if I create one variable at the postExecute scope with a different path for each ExecSQLTask and the exact same expression, but if there's a better way to reference the expression across tasks in events, please let me know.

Thanks.

I'm also trying to parameterize the execute sql task sqlStatementSource variable with a value like

```
     DELETE FROM db.TableStatsHistory WHERE TABLENAME = '@[System::SourceName]' 
and LastUpdated = CURRENT_DATE;
```

but that's not working either.  It doesn't give me a 'parameter mismatch' error like when I create a parameter within the task, but it behaves as if the system variable value is blank or null.

Basically, I want a method equivalent to SQL Server stored procedures with parameters, but I don't think Teradata has anything like that.  I'm thinking now I should store the SQL in a table on Teradata and look up the SQL to execute with the embedded parameter token.

Comment: I'm also looking at parameterizing the execute SQL task for the SQLStatementSource variable with a value like

Answer (score 0):

Having the "System::SourceName" is the issue. It has the scope that is not compatible with the design of the package. 
Not sure how exactly you designed your package, but an appropriate fix could be in creating a User (package level) variable that gets the value of "System::SourceName" and then you can use it in the PostExecute event.

Comment: yes, it is.  I have a user variable (package level) that contains the system variable.  I'm calling it in the onPostExecute event.  How is what you're suggesting different from what I'm doing?

Comment: The proper syntax for a SSIS expression to parametrize execute SQL Task is "DELETE FROM db.TableStatsHistory WHERE TABLENAME = '" + @[System::SourceName] + "' and LastUpdated = CURRENT_DATE;"

Comment: I have it working, just not the way I wanted, as I had to create 80 variables at 40 different levels of the onPostExecute event.  Syntax wasn't a problem, I was trying to get the same SQL executed for 40 different table values.  I have that now with my block of SQL in one place.